# how to show the data when id's are comma speparated in table?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table of packages in which

```
 Package_id   name     description
  1           A        abcdef
  2           B        ghijkl
  3           C        mnopq
```

and another table is user_comparisons

```
  u_c_id     user_id   package_ids
   1            1       1,2
   2            2       2,1
   3            1       1,3
```

i want to show packages with respect to user_comparisons against the users , how can i do that? if any one can help it will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I want to show packages like

```
user Comparisons # 1 

   Package 1                  Package 2 
  Name     description     Name          Description
```

User Comaprison    # 2

```
 Package 1                   Package 3
 Name     Description         Name        Description
```

Comment: The best solution is to restructure (normalize) your database to remove the comma-separated values into their own table

Answer (score 6):

use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    user_comparison a
        INNER JOIN packages b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.Package_ID, a.package_IDs) > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/884bf/3)
- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

The current design of the database is bad. Consider normalizing the tables into three table design.

Comment: yeah i got that, but problem is that i want to show in my view as i edited the question and mention it above.

Comment: @JW +1 for SQLFiddle Demo Sir.

Comment: each package is of different row?

Comment: no, each comparison shows in a row, and package is in align with the another package id which exist in user comparison row 1 and row 2.